# yesod how to show the pure value of a PersistInt64 key

Tags: haskell, key, yesod, persist

```
Dog
    name Text
    race Text

getAllDogsR :: Handler Html
getAllDogsR = do
    Dogs<- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc DogName]
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <ul>
                $forall Entity dogid dog <- Dogs
                    <li>
                        #{show $ unKey (dogid)}
       |]
```

When I run this code I will get a list of all dog keys that are in my database
like this:

- PersistInt64 1
- PersistInt64 2
- PersistInt64 3
- PersistInt64 4
- etc

but what I actually want is to show the pure value of the key
like this:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- etc

My question is how can I achieve this.

Comment: Does `#{case dogid of PersistInt64 x -> show $ unKey x}` work?

Comment: does not work unfortunately

Comment: The function you want is [fromPersistValueText](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.2.3.0/docs/Database-Persist-Types.html#v:fromPersistValueText).

However you can also have `module Model.Id` for anchors, ids and things like that. The module will contain class for id rendering: 

    `class PersistId a where
      persistId :: Key a -> Text`

and a couple of instances:

    `instance PersistId Dog where
      persistId = either T.pack id . fromPersistValueText . unKey`

will do that you want. I think this will be convenient enough.

Comment: Although you have asked how to print out the IDs as plain text, I suspect you are actually just going to print out the IDs to the user. If you eventually want to use those IDs in a URL, you can do so without any conversion: `<a href=@{GetSpecificDogR dogId}> #{dogName dog} </a>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the key out of a `KeyBackend` first, like so:

```
extractKey :: KeyBackend backend entity -> String
extractKey = extractKey' . unKey
  where extractKey' (PersistInt64 k) = show k
        extractKey' _ = ""
```

You should now be able to do

```
#{extractKey dogid}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
#{show $ unKey (dogid)}
```

to

```
#{toPathPiece dogid}
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide a more detailed answer with a working example, and possibly some contextual explanation. A one line comment is more suited as just that - a comment on the question.

Comment: @AlexOsborn: It isn't just a comment, though. It's an answer. It does exactly what he's asking for.

Comment: `toPathPiece` is defined in the `path-pieces` package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-pieces), in the `Web.PathPieces` module. If you have a `(Key x)` you can use `toPathPiece x`.